# Renderorder of MapElements and MapLayers in WP8 Map

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm using the WP8 Map-Control to display various content like polygons, polylines and images.

Images are rendered in MapLayers, polygons and polylines in the MapElements-Collection. It seems like all polygons and polylines are always rendered first and then all the MapLayers on top it.

Is it possible to change the render order of polylines, so that they are drawn on top of some maplayers? I didn't find any ZIndex property...

Thanks, Tom

Answer (score 0):

The Z-Index will be determined by the order the layers are defined in the app (either in code or XAML). Change the order there to later Z-Index.